# OBIEE Calculated Item with percentage value

Tags: formula, percentage, calculated-columns, calculated-field, obiee

[image]

I have rows of EBITDA, EBIT, etc, they are Calculated Items.
For example, `EBITDA = Revenue-Expense`
It is relevant for numeric columns, but not for percentages columns. The percentage column should keep the formula which is row operation : `Achv(EBITDA) = Actual/Target` , not `Achv(EBITDA) = Revenue-Expense`

I've tried using grand total but it's only one usage per view. Is there any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Do you want the Achv. column to be null or hidden in some way for the percentages?

Comment: The Achv. -22.8% comes from 100%-122.8%, but it should be 6,767.. / 7,667.. = 88% which violates the calculation of the row